# Is there a way to use group to get activerecord models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table with a type column, and I would like to group all of the records by that type...

I know I can do:

```
MyTable.group(:type).count
```

And then I get something like:

```
{ "some-type" => 123, "another-type" => 456 }
```

But rather than getting the count, I want the actual records, like this:

```
{ "some-type" => <ActiveRecordRelation: [<id="1" type="some-type">, <id="60" type="some-type">...]>, "another-type" => <ActiveRecordRelation: [<id="99" type="another-type">...] }
```

So basically, I am looking for a way I can just do:

```
MyTable.group(:type).each do |key, values|
  # ... do stuff with values...
end
```

rather than having to do this:

```
MyTable.uniq.pluck('type').each do |type|
  values = MyTable.where(:type => type)
  # ... do stuff with values
end
```

Comment: `group` causes a `GROUP BY` in your query.  What you're actually looking for, oddly enough is `group_by`, which takes a block, and is a Ruby Enumerable method.

Comment: yeah...  I was wondering if there was an activerecord way to do this not an Enumerable way...

Comment: Nah, that's not how `GROUP BY` works in SQL, unfortunately.  The best you're going to be able to do, if you use Postgres, is to do a `json_agg` and get the fields back as JSON.  You could then iterate over the values in the hash to instantiate the ActiveRecord models yourself, but there isn't an automated way at this point.